# Is it possible to build a thread-safe linked list that scales and provides read, insert and remove?

Tags: performance, linked-list, lock-free

I've been looking for implementations of scalable linked-lists that can be used safely my multiple threads in parallel, that can **read**, **insert** and **remove** elements from it.

However, I was only able to found papers and theoretical descriptions of them, no libraries are available.

First of all, it is mandatory to use intrinsics or can I do this with higher-level atomics (e.g. OpenMP atomic)? Will that hurt scalability?

In second place, implementations usually provide **insert** and **remove** functions. The only way to traverse the list in another thread and at the same time is me to implement it, right?

Thanks

Comment: Did you read the thread here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19609417/atomic-operations-for-lock-free-doubly-linked-list

Comment: If you have a Haswell CPU you can use [TSX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transactional_Synchronization_Extensions) for all that, in theory that should be the best performance and scalability.

Comment: @user1767754, that thread doesn't answer my questions.

Comment: @Leeor, thanks, but I have Sandy Bridge processors only. :-(

Comment: See [this library](http://libcds.sourceforge.net/)